# ADF - get table name from dataset

Tags: dynamic, azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory dynamic content seems very powerful and very under-documented.

Lets say I have a simple (non-dynamic) dataset pointing to a SQL table:

[image]

And then in a Copy Data task I want to reference that table in the Pre-copy script, e.g. to clear out all the data.

[image]

How can I pull the table name out of the dataset? Its right there in the Json so surely there's a way?

e.g I see ADF has an activities collection that you can pull things from, e.g. `@activity("Activity Name").output` ... is there anything similar for pulling properties from datasets? Or from the current Copy Data activity and then get through to the dataset from there?

The official documentation gives a [few quick examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) but is very light on details. e.g. when you do `@activity("Activity Name").output` you are hitting some sort of object model but what other objects are available and what are their properties? Anyone got anything on that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the dataset values in your pipeline. As you are hardcoding the table name value in your dataset, you can use the same hardcoded value in your pre-copy script.

Or you can create a dataset parameter and pass the value to the parameter from the pipeline and use the same value in any activities inside the pipeline.

**Example**:

1. Create a pipeline variable or parameter.

[image]

2. Create dataset parameter in the dataset.

[image]

3. Pass the variable value to the dataset parameter in the copy data activity sink. Use the same variable in your pre-copy script.

Pre-copy script:

```
@{concat('Truncate table ',variables('tbname'))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @codeulike, had it solved your problem? else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, I didn't think ADF and its proprietary expression language were that intuitive when I first started working with it.  But like most things, it just takes time to get to know it.  I spent a lot of time with [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), and did some practice and you can work with the **outputs from activities**, so say if you had a Lookup that fetched the schema and table name you wanted to work with, then you can reference that in later activities, eg `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.someTableName`.  The easiest way to see what an activity output is, is to run it and look in the Output section; hover over the little 'exit' sign and it shows you the json which you can navigate a bit like an object model,  eg `value.someVal1.someVal2.`

[image]